Fixing the Training Function for an LSTM model built from scratch
So, I’m currently trying to build a custom-built LSTM model. To do so, I’m trying to build the custom LSTM from scratch first and slowly modify it. However, right now I’m having difficulty making the model learn at all.
Here is my code for my LSTM function.
class LSTM_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_sz, hidden_sz, out_sz, bs):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_sz = input_sz
        self.hidden_size = hidden_sz
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(input_sz, hidden_sz * 4))
        self.U = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_sz, hidden_sz * 4))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(hidden_sz * 4))
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(hidden_sz, out_sz)
        self.init_weights()

    def init_weights(self):
        stdv = 1.0 / math.sqrt(self.hidden_size)
        for weight in self.parameters():
            weight.data.uniform_(-stdv, stdv)

    def forward(self, x, init_states=None):
        bs, seq_sz, _ = x.size()
        hidden_seq = []
        if init_states is None:
            h_t, c_t = (torch.zeros(bs, self.hidden_size).to(x.device),
                        torch.zeros(bs, self.hidden_size).to(x.device))
        else:
            h_t, c_t = init_states

        for t in range(seq_sz):
            x_t = x[:, t, :]
            if x_t.size()[0] != bs:
                fill_in = torch.zeros(bs-x_t[0], seq_sz)
                x_t - torch.cat((x_t, fill_in), 0)

            gates = torch.matmul(x_t, self.W) + torch.matmul(h_t, self.U) + self.bias
            i_t, f_t, g_t, o_t = gates.chunk(4, 1)
            i_t, f_t, g_t, o_t = torch.sigmoid(i_t), torch.sigmoid(f_t), torch.tanh(g_t), torch.sigmoid(i_t)
            c_t = f_t * c_t + i_t * g_t
            h_t = o_t * torch.tanh(c_t)
            hidden_seq.append(h_t)
        out = self.fc1(h_t)
        return out, (h_t, c_t)

Here is my training function.
def train_model(data_loader, model, loss_function, optimizer):
    num_batches = len(data_loader)
    total_loss = 0
    model.train()
    hidden = None
    #torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
    for X, y in data_loader:
        output, hidden = model(X, hidden)
        loss = loss_function(output, y)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        #loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()

        total_loss += loss.item()

    avg_loss = total_loss / num_batches
    print(f"Train loss: {avg_loss}")
    return avg_loss

Running it gets an initial error message, which requires me to put the retain_graph(True), but after that I get more errors. (Also to clarify the data is in this order [batch, sequence, features])
I also notice that removing the hidden variable for the training function, the program gives an output, but the model does not learn at all, probably because it’s throwing away the hidden state I think.
I've tried to do some research, but everything seems to be going to a deadend. Removing the hidden state part from the training function makes the program run, but it is no longer learning anything and outputs like a static line (I'm training my model on stock market data). However, addressing the issues causes me to run into variosu different issues.
